# how to fix chown missing operand

Tags: command-line, chown

in very new to linux and i am trying to install something and this is what I got.

```
 sudo chown root:root/usr/bin/bwrap && sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/bwrap 

 chown: missing operand after ‘root:root/usr/bin/bwrap’
 Try 'chown --help' for more information.
```

I'm not sure what I'm messing up on.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why do your instructions tell you to execute this command? It should _never_ be needed to change file modes on files in `/usr/bin` on Ubuntu, and certainly not setting their setuid bit, which will likely cause other breakage.

Comment: If you are very new to Linux, and are indeed on Ubuntu, note that a _huge_ collection of software is directly available through `apt install`. Don't follow arbitrary installation guides you find somewhere on the internet. Instead search for "how do I install XYZ **on Ubuntu 22.04**", or just try `apt search` for the program in the command line. `/usr/bin/bwrap` installs simply and correctly using `apt install bubblewrap`.

Answer (score 2):

Put a space between the ownership parameter and the resource:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/bwrap && sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/bwrap
```